# Using DEM to orthorectify satellite images

Tags: arcgis-desktop, orthorectification

How can I orthorectify satellite images through DEM (in any GIS software)? I am not getting any specific method for doing this. I have done in ENVI software but it requires RPC file but I am unable to create RPC file in it. In ArcGIS software it require GCP file and I am unable to get the GCP file.

Comment: Orfeo toolbox has an orthorectification tool but I do not have experience using that tool.  Here is the documentation:  https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_OrthoRectification.html

Comment: Please do not post the same question again, rather edit the old one if you have some new/different info: [How to Orthorectify satellite images through DEM? (in any GIS software) because I am not getting any specific method to do this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431720/how-to-orthorectify-satellite-images-through-dem-in-any-gis-software-because)

Comment: @TomazicM your referenced answer has been removed unfortunately